# Installing EBImage on Windows 7

Tags: r

I'm very new to R. I've tried to install the package EBImage

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
> biocLite("EBImage")
```

and got the Warning:

> installed directory not writable, cannot update packages 'foreign',
> 'lattice', 'Matrix', 'mgcv', 'nlme'

As I've tried to load an image

```
> f = system.file("images", "C:/aeskuimg/Patterns/Homogenious/h.jpg", package="EBImage")
> hom = readImage(f)
```

I've got the error:

> Error in readImage(f) : Unable to determine type: Empty filename.

I suspect this is because of the prior warning.

Is there any solution there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning can be ignored, it indicates that some packages were installed in a way that does not allow them to be updated, probably by an Administrator account whereas you're running as a regular user. To use an R package, load it first

```
library(EBImage)
```

Probably just

```
readImage("C:/aeskuimg/Patterns/Homogenious/h.jpg")
```

will work (R has tab completion, so no need to try too hard at typing the correct path; also `file.choose()` provides graphical navigation).

`system.file()` is used to specify a path relative to the location in which a package has been installed, and is typically used to reference an example file the package authors have distributed with the package. Probably after your command the value of `f` is `character(0)`, which is R's way of saying that that the path you specified, relative to the installed location of the EBImage package, does not exist; `system.file()` has an argument `mustWork=TRUE` that will generate an error if the file path is incorrect.

Comment: That helped, thanks a lot! EBImage seems to be an amazing package.